# Javascript or JQuery string get substring with certain prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I have an element with many classes, I would like to access a specific class to get the last digit of it (I realize a data-attribute or ID may have been better options but for now I am stuck with class).  I already am able to select the element using it's ID so I only need to identify what the last digit of the my-target-* is.

Example

```
<div class="foo bar apple my-target-1"></div>
```

I would like to get the class my-target-* and then extract the 1 from it.

Comment: is it always  my-target-*?

Comment: yes it will always be my-target-*

Comment: Perfect case to use data attributes, not classes

Comment: `element.classList` might be a good start. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over all the elements containing 'my-target', assuming it is the last class, split the classes by space, get the last class, split it by '-' then get the needed value to extract.

Here is a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("[class*= my-target]").each(function(){

    var extract= $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop().split('-').pop();
    $("#result").html(extract);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo bar apple my-target-1"></div>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: nice for actually answering the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery selector that should target your element:

```
$("[class*=my-target]");
```

But this may be more general than you need: this uses the CSS *substring* selector `*=`, so this would also match elements like the following:

```
<div class="not-my-target"></div>
```

You can try a combination of selectors to get something more specific:

```
 $("[class^=my-target], [class*= my-target"]);
```

This combines the CSS *starts with* selector, with the contains.

Now to grab the data that you want from the class name you'll need to do some string parsing on the `class` attribute:

```
var numberToExtract = -1;

var elem = $("[class*=my-target-]");

if (elem)
{
    classes = elem.attr("class").split(/\s+/);

    $.each(classes, function(idx, el)
    {
        if (el.startsWith("my-target-"))
        {
            numberToExtract = el.split("-").pop();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is neater if you use a data element to do this

```
<div class="foo bar apple my-target-1" data-target="1"></div>
```

And you get this by doing:

```
$('.my-target-1').data('target')
```

It's better than parsing the class

Comment: I do not know whether it will be my-target-1 or 2 or 100.  I can select the element using element selector or the ID but I need to access the class and get the # from it

Comment: Then you can use simply 'my-target' as name of the class instead 'my-target' and get the #. I mean, if you have the element selected you can access the data element to get the value you need

Answer (score 0):

To get any one starting with those classes try this

```
$('div[id^=foo bar apple my-target]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck using a class instead of a data attribute, you can extract the full string of classes from the object you've found with:

```
obj.attr('class')
```

and then match that against a regular expression that uses word boundaries and capturing parentheses to extract the number at the end of `'my-target-*'`

Answer (score 0):

You must have ID to catch the particular div or span content.
Be Careful , Perhaps , you have a class and a subclass .

```
<div id='id' class='myclass mysubclass' >Testing</div>
```

So if you want to have the class selector, do the following :

`var className = '.'+$('#id').attr('class').split(' ').join('.')`

and you will have

`.myclass.mysubclass`

Now if you want to select all elements that have the same class such as div above :

```
var class=$('.'+$('#id').attr('class').split(' ').join('.'))
```

that means

`var class=$('.myclass.mysubclass')`

If you want second class into multiple classes using into a element

`var class_name = $('#id').attr('class').split(' ')[1]`;`

or You can simply use `var className = $('#id').attr('class');` this will return full name class and subclass then handle it using JQuery/JavaScript substring method.